# Hibernate one-to-one (on foreign key) vs one-to-one (on primary key)

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys, primary-key, one-to-one

I have questions about
What are the benefits of using a `one-to-one` association on **foreign key** or a `one-to-one` association on the **primary key**?

I've read the documentation of Hibernate available at: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-121

Can someone tell me with details the plus of using the first or the second implementation?

Another question, I have a `one-to-one` unidirectional relationship between User and Perimeter.
(User ----> Perimeter) and I want to use the association based on the foreign key.
Could I reverse the direction into (User <---- Perimeter) so the table User stay intact?
I think that is not reasonable (perimeter.getUser() !!!) but it's technically possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to advantages mentioned by JB Nizet and thanks to another person told me that the one-to-one based on foreign key is more flexible. let's consider that i use a one-to-one on foreign key (User <--- Perimeter) , if the requirements of the application changes to need multiple Users  for any Perimeter, If i shared the primary key, I'll have much more refactoring to do. But as i used the foreign key, all i do is relax the unique constraint ;)

Answer (score 3):

I see two advantages

- Having the choice lets you map existing schemas, whatever they have chosen as strategy
- using a foreign key in A pointing to the ID in B, Hibernate knows that there is no B for a given A if the foreign key is null. It can't know that when primary keys are used. So it's more efficient to use a foreign key if the association is optional.

For your second question, yes, of course it's possible. That is called a bidirectional OneToOne association:

```
public class User {
    // ...

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Perimeter perimeter;
}

public class Perimeter {
    // ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "perimeter")
    private User user;
}
```

Comment: first of all thank you for your reply, i understood the two advantages. but for my second question i don't want a bidirectional relationship, just User <-- Perimeter direction because (i refer to the xml mapping in the hibernate documentation i don't know annotations very well) bidirectional oblige me to add a column into the User table but i don't want to touch the User table

Comment: Making an association bidirectional doesn't change anything to the schema. If you want the perimeter table to contain the join column instead of the user table, then simply do it.

Answer (score 1):

**one to one relationship using primary key association**

In this association one-to-one relationships occurs when one entity is related to exactly one occurrence in another entity.

here is the link for example:
          [primary key association](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example/)

**one to one relationship using foreign key association**

In the same example do the following changes:

In StockDetail.java

```
    private Integer stockDetailsId;
    //with setter and getter
    //remove stockId and it's setter and getter
```

in stock.hbm.xml

```
    <id name="stockId" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="STOCK_ID" />
                <generator class="assigned" />
      </id>
```

in StockDetail.hbm.xml

```
    <id name="stockDetailsId" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="STOCK_DETAILS_ID" />
                <generator class="assigned"/>
     </id>
    <many-to-one name="stock" 

    class="com.test.common.Stock" column="STOCK_ID" />
```

in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    //this is optional property if you want to create database table's according to your hbm file's.

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```